# $I_m - AB$ invertible if and only if $I_n - BA$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

> Let $A$ and  $B$ be $m\times n$ and $n\times m$ matrices respectively.
>
> 1. Prove that if $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$ then it is also an eigenvalue of $BA$
> 2. Prove that $I_m-AB$ is invertible if and only if $I_n-BA$ is invertible.

Part (1) is easy:

$$ABx=\lambda x$$

By definition, $x\ne 0$, and by assumption $\lambda \ne 0$. So we have $Bx\ne 0$

Now,
$$B(AB)x=(BA)Bx=\lambda Bx$$
and so $Bx$ and a non-zero vector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

---

My problem is I have no idea how to use this to do (2). Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an $n\times n$ matrix $T$ if and only if $\lambda I_n-T$ fails to be invertible.

Comment: Something seems off here, $AB$ will be an $m \times n$ matrix, so how are you going to subtract it from a square matrix?

Comment: @Merlinsbeard Sorry my typo in the post, corrected. Thanks!

Comment: ah ok, i found an answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237779/i-m-ab-is-invertible-if-and-only-if-i-n-ba-is-invertible?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in Carmichael's comment, we have that the following are equivalent:

(1) $(I_n-BA)$ is invertible.

(2) $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $BA$.

(3) $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $AB$.

(4) $(I_m-AB)$ is invertible.

You've proven that $(2) \iff (3)$, so just note that

$$(I-M)v \iff Mv=Iv=v$$

for any matrix $M$.

Answer (score 4):

For part (2):

Let $_{}−$ be invertible and let’s consider the following matrix expression
$(_{}−)(_{}−)^{−1}$ which you can verify simplifies to $BA$.

If that is true, then what is $(_{}−)[(_{}−)^{−1}+I_{n}]$?

You can easily construct a similar argument if you first let $_{}−$ be invertible.